copy some apt packages so that they can be installed offline
Often I have to use a live cd installation of Ubuntu like the 20.04 lts.
I found that there are lot of tools and packages that are missing like brasero and wodim
However I'm unable to always access the mirrors for downloading them.
I was thinking instead of downloading them on a flash drive and just connect it open a terminal and do something like
dpkg -i *.deb
Then I realized that each package has lot of dependency.
How can I be sure that I download all the packages I need including the dependencies so that I can install everything I need from the flash drive?
Given my case of Ubuntu 20 what is the archive address for the packages?
I know that I could include the packages in the Ubuntu live dvd but this is not the target of the question.

BTW in the question you ask about Ubuntu 20, this is a version number of Ubuntu Core. If you are not using Ubuntu Core please edit the question and put in the actual version info.

To list the dependencies of a package
apt-cache depends <package-name>

to download a package only, without installing it:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall --download-only [package-name]

Downloaded packages are found in /var/cache/apt/archives
Note that if you copy a set of packages to a USB drive, and any are later installed from the USB drive using sudo dpkg [package-name].deb, you might be installing an older version.  You would not get any warning that a later version exists in the official repositories, unless the application itself checks for updates.

See my answers titled: How to create CD/DVD .ISO repository of .deb packages? and How to use a .iso image as a CD-ROM/DVD Repository? And how to install packages using the repository? . To maintain a complete repository without dependency issues for a version say 24.04, I'd copy all the apps installed and updates installed manually at an accessible location. For that I need to copy the contents of /var/cache/apt/archives/ directory when updates were made/apps installed. Copying all those over time will accumulate different versions of same package, from which you can create a repo of the latest with help of answers I've linked previously.
